# PHP configuration to enable sessions

Tags: session, php

On our development server, sessions handling works fine. On our production server, it doesnt.

phpinfo on the development server shows:

```
                 session
Session Support                 enabled
Registered save handlers            files user mm sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx
```

phpinfo on the production server shows:

```
                 session
Session Support                    enabled
Registered save handlers          files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx
```

What is "mm sqlite" and could it be causing the problem? How do I enable this? What are these settings anyway?

---

The rest of the settings are common between the two:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

---

Can the absence of the "mm sqlite" stop PHP sessions from working when shifting from development to production?

Comment: php5 is current PHP version for ages already. no need to specify it

Comment: Nope, absence of the "mm sqlite" **can not** stop PHP sessions from working.      
And configuration settings is the least reason for something not work. It is your code, dude. It's your code, which you'd better start to debug

Comment: Not exactly Col. I've framed a new question that also describes why I'm facing a problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740884/creating-new-tmp-folder-for-php-to-use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from http://devzone.zend.com/article/141

There are a couple built-in options for storing session data. The session handler is set in the php.ini under the directive named

```
session.save_handler
```

**sqlite**
Optionally, you can store session data in an sqlite database. To do so, use a configuration such as:

```
session.save_handler = sqlite
session.save_path = /tmp/phpsess.db
```

**mm**
For high-performance session storage, you can store session data in memory with the mm shared-memory module. You'll need to compile php with the mm module support. Here is a tutorial to configure session handling with mm ( http://www.zend.com/tips/tips.php?id=164&single=1 ). Note that since session date is stored in RAM, you should consider it volatile data, and it's lost with power outage or a reboot.

Note: the link in the above tutorial is outdated. You can retrieve the mm module from the OSSP.org website.

Comment: from the comments of that page: `Should be: session.save_handler = sqlite` which is logical

Comment: fix the session.save_handler to sqlite please

Comment: @Codemwnci       What should be the value of session.save_path if session.save_handler is set to `mm` ?

Answer (score 0):

What does the rest of the 'sessions' settings look like on your phpinfo page?

Particularly, what is the value of "session.save_handler" and "session.save_path"?

Here is some more information: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

"mm" and "sqlite" are alternative save handlers available for you to use. By default, php uses "files" which will store session data on your local server.