# session_start() does not set $_SESSION at all

Tags: php, session, cpanel

I have the following identical code on my development and production server. It works on the development end, but not on the production side:

```
<?php
$s = session_start();
mail('me@example.com', 'Site-test', "s=$s; SESSION=".serialize($_SESSION), "MIME...");
```

Development server shows:

```
s=1; SESSION=a:4:{s:20:"user_timezone_region";s:13:"Pacific/Samoa";s:4:"lang";s:1:"1";s:12:"sess_user_id";s:3:"225";s:14:"sess_user_type";s:1:"S";}
```

Production server shows:

```
s=1; SESSION=a:0:{}
```

There is something wrong with my PHP settings on the production server which I'm hoping to diagnose. Yes, this is linked to my other two questions recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740791/php-configuration-to-enable-sessions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740884/creating-new-tmp-folder-for-php-to-use).

More details:

- I have cPanel running on this server
- PHP error_log did NOT report the above to be an error (note that the variable 's' is '1')
- The differences in phpinfo() for the two is mentioned in the first link

Comment: Just a small sanity check: it seems that on your dev server $_SESSION is already populated elsewhere. Are you doing the same on your production one?

Comment: Check the session cookie's ID as set from your production server between requests. Most likely you'll see it change between requests, indicating a brand new (blank) session is being created.

Answer (score 1):

The session, when first started for a new client, is actually empty. That could mean that on the dev server you see a session of a returning client, while on productive — the session of a first-time client.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you test your session in such odd way? 
Why not to make such a simple script

```
<? 
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;
echo "Page reloaded ".$_SESSION['counter']++." times.<br>
<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.session_name().'='.session_id().">reload</a>"; 
?>
```

if it works, your sessions works perfectly, but there is something wrong with passing identifier.
If not... there ought to be some error message.