# PHP.ini example to enable sessions?

Tags: php

PHP newbie here, but I can't find a straight answer online. Given the bellow session section of my phpinfo, what would I need in a php.ini to enable sessions in the most basic of ways? Thanks :)

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: What does not work? Are there errors?  Also, possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740791/php-configuration-to-enable-sessions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP installations do not need any special configuration to enable sessions. They are [enabled by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php).

You should make sure you have `session_start();` as the first line in any page that you intend to use sessions; it should be the very first line, before any whitespace (an empty line, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must increase your session as follow:

`session.cookie_lifetime 0   0` and `session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440`

to

`session.cookie_lifetime 86400 86400` and `session.gc_maxlifetime  86400   86400` cumulatively.

86400 means 1 day.

This will allow your system to use "session_start()" which will have 1 day life.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There are a following built-in options for storing session data. The session handler is set in the php.ini under the directive named

```
session.save_handler
```

You can also give sqlite db to store your session like

```
session.save_handler = sqlite
session.save_path = /tmp/phpsess.db
```

Comment: Just note that `/tmp` is a 'world-readable' directory and can be utilized by other members on the server but if it's your own personal dev server, it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your current `save_handler` is set to store session date in files on the system. The problem is that your `save_path` looks like it doesn't currently have a value. You will need to add a `save_path` so PHP knows where to put those files.

[PHP: Runtime Configuration #session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)

Take a look at [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php#79899) where a user describes having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

After installing  and settings, rebooting solves problem. Manually starting servers did produce the result above. Definetly somethings does not load properly when starting the server manually.

I hope still helps someone.