# Setting sessions variables in php functions

Tags: php, session

I set a SESSION inside a function and I'm trying to accses it from another function.
I think that the session is set only for that function, can i do anything about it?

thx!

the code:

```
    $admin_password = sha1(md5('1234')); // סיסמת מנהל
    function login($password,$admin_password)   {
        $password = sha1(md5($password));
        if ($password == $admin_password)   {
            $_SESSION['admin_ver'] = $admin_password;
            return true;
        }   else    {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function log1($admin_password)  {
        if (isset($_SESSION['admin_ver']))  {
            if ($_SESSION['admin_ver'] == $admin_password)  {
                return true;
            }   else    {
                return false;
            }
        }   else    {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I tried to run this page on another server and it worked. Can anyone suggest the reason? thx again!

Comment: Make sure you have added `session_start()` on top of the page

Comment: Session is a global variable. It can be accessed anywhere and is not limited by scope

Comment: There is session_start() at the top.
It still not working for some reason...

Comment: Are you sure that `function login` is called first ?

Comment: Pheeew it was really tough to copy this -> `// סיסמת מנהל` so anyone interested in knowing what does it mean, it means "// Password Manager"

Comment: Have you tested to make sure it's making it to the part where the session var is set? Echo something in that condition.

Comment: ofcourse. there is a login form that called it before anything else.

And I did test the return false is the says the SESSION is not exist.

and cappY, it's Hebrew :)

Comment: session_start() must be called before any output is generated if will fail if you have send anything to the user already. You should see a warning if can't send headers. Check if calling it returns true /i.e.: session_start() or die('error starting session');/

Comment: I know, the session_start is at the top of the page.
please read my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you read the basics of a session variables: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

A session variable is completely global to that page visit (aka a session), any page/function can access it which has called session_start();

Comment: I know the basics, but i couldn't think of anything else that can cause it.

Comment: "I think that the session is set only for that function" this is not the case, session variables don't work like that. It's more likely a get/set issue.

Comment: I didn't explain myself well.
I tried to say that SOMEHOW it's set only for the function.. because i can't find any problem with the code.

Comment: Please read [why w3schools is bad](http://www.w3fools.com/) and link the official documentation. tia!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put this code `<?php session_start(); ?>`on every page you want to use your `$_SESSION` variables.

I works for me all the time so it should work with yours also. And take note: you should use `session_start();` function whenever you want to use `$_SESSION` variables. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your latest edit, I am thinking that php on your server is not configured properly to support sessions,

To configure, open php.ini file and define the following params,

Define path to save sessions

```
session.save_path = "C:\php\sessiondata\"
```

Define handler

```
session.save_handler = files
```

Whether to use cookies.

```
session.use_cookies = 1
```

Name of the session (used as cookie name).

```
session.name = PHPSESSID
```

Define Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

The path for which the cookie is valid.

```
session.cookie_path = /
```

The domain for which the cookie is valid.

```
session.cookie_domain =
```

Handler used to serialize data. php is the standard serializer of PHP.

```
session.serialize_handler = php
```

MORE ON SESSION CONFIGURATION : http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

REF: http://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP

SIMILAR HELPFUL THREAD: [PHP.ini example to enable sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705786/php-ini-example-to-enable-sessions)