# PHP session files are empty

Tags: php

I have PHP code with sessions enabled. Session files are being created in `tmp` directory but its empty, that’s why my browser Internet Explorer and Chrome are not able to pick up the session and display it across the pages.

Here is my PHP code.

Page2.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test3.php" method="post">
Username: <br><input type="text" name="username"></br>
<input type="submit" name = 'submit1' value= 'Login'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page3.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
echo "<br> Hi $username.</br>";
?>

<form action="test4.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name = 'submit' value= 'click me'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Page4.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "<br> Hi $username.</br>";
?>
```

Comment: I've had this issue before - check your `php.ini` configuration - if it's not set properly, `$_SESSION` won't work no matter what.  Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705786/php-ini-example-to-enable-sessions) for some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved I had to change `session.cookie_path` in `php.ini` to `/` instead `/tmp`.

Comment: Can there be an explanation added?  Why would would the path be root?

Comment: It's the path relative to the site (e.g. the / in http://example.com/) not the path on the local filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `session.save_path` in your server’s `php.ini` file.

You can see what it is set to now by checking `phpinfo()` output.

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Look for the `session` block which should look something like this; screenshot from my MAMP setup:

[image]

Then in your `php.ini` should be a chunk of configuration like this:

```
; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this 
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
; As of PHP 4.0.1, you can define the path as:
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in 
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and 
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if you 
; or your OS have problems with lots of files in one directory, and is 
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle lots of sessions.
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;

session.save_path = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
```

Make sure that path actually exists on your system & that the Apache server can write to it. If the directory does not exist or cannot be written to, adjust that as needed to match your setup.

I found [this site](http://support.ultimatelocator.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/60/0/php-session-problems-warning-session_start-opentmp-failed-permission-denied) has lots of good info on how to deal with issues like this as well.

Comment: its set to `session.save_path = "W;/tmp"
`

Comment: im on linux centOS, i tried changing the path to `/tmp` but not working.file not being created. so i have to give it to `W;/tmp`, file are being created but empty.

Comment: i changed the directory to `/tmp` its creating session files but empty.