# php user_id in session not working

Tags: php, session

i need some help about $_session. My team have develop an Web-Application and there are a problem
that i cannot get the user_id on the $_session['user_id']? 
on the mailing view:

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&$_SESSION['angemeldet']){

    $objModel = new MAILING();
    $id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

and on the login part:

```
if ($login_success) {
    //die();
    $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $login_success['user_email'];
    $_SESSION['user_role'] = $login_success['role'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login_success['user_id'];
    if ($login_success['role'] == 'admin'){
       header('Location: ?page=admin');
    }else{
       header('Location: ?page=home');
    }

}
```

the  problem that if i try the codes on localhost, it work perfectly and on the server $_SESSION['user_id'] is somehow like empty??

could someone help me?
thx b4.

Comment: Are sessions actived on server development?

Comment: Did you started the session with `session_start()` in both files?

Comment: i would check if `session_start()` is called in the mailing view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I would check if you have enabled sessions on your server environment.
See the answer by answer by Adarsh here: [PHP.ini example to enable sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705786/php-ini-example-to-enable-sessions)

Also, it can be useful to print out and debug you varialbes along the way to see where you lose your data/information. Try using the `print_r()` function for debuging. Try using `print_r($login_success); print_r($_SESSION); exit();` after you have set your variables to print out all of the variables data.