# Why session is deleted on page reload? - PHP

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

This is my code:

INDEX.PHP

```
    // index.php

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'red';
    $_SESSION['animal']   = 'dog';
    $_SESSION['time']     = time();

    print_r($_SESSION);
```

The result is:

```
    Array
    (
        [favcolor] => red
        [animal] => dog
        [time] => 1439307117
    )
```

---

After visiting the home, I go to the test page:

---

TEST.PHP

```
    // test.php

    session_start();

    echo $_SESSION['favcolor'];
    echo $_SESSION['animal'];
    echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

    print_r($_SESSION);
```

The result is:

```
    Array ()
```

---

Why?

Comment: Did you check for a cookie getting stored in your browser? Did you enable error_reporting?

Comment: Hello, what server tool are you using for testing? (xamp, wamp easyphp..)?

Comment: You need to enable sessions on your PHP page see http://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP . You may also find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740791/php-configuration-to-enable-sessions

Comment: Using the same domain name to access the two scripts? `var_dump($_COOKIE);` after `session_start();` to check that the session cookie is being returned.

Comment: Does your browser accept cookies? https://www.whatismybrowser.com/are-cookies-enabled

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had the folder "**var/lib/php/session**" without write permissions.

Setting permissions with the command "**chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session**" everything is back to work.

Thanks to all for the tips.